# For functions that take a pointer parameter, do I pass the address in a call?

Tags: c, pointers, parameter-passing

For instance:

```
void Sample_Function(char * ptr){ //Stuff }

void Some_Other_Function(){
    char *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
    // Is this correct?
    Sample_Function(p);
    // Or this?
    Sample_Function(*p);
}
```

Since free() takes an address and not the pointed-to byte I'm guessing the first option is correct?

Additionally, for functions that return a pointer:

```
// Is this correct?
return p;
// Or this?
return *p;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

type of p is `char*` And type of *p is `char`. So `Sample_Function(p)` is a valid call.
If your function is:

```
char* Some_Other_Function(){ //things}
```

then you should return `p` not `*p` for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

You should call it like `Sample_Function(p)` if `p` is a pointer or with `Sample_Function(&a)` if `a` is not a pointer.

If a function is returning a pointer, it is returning an address, so you should use `return p;` or `return &a;`.

Comment: Then at least 'a' should be char.